# Калькулятор с коэфицентом

Tags: jquery

Есть 2 поля select, в каждом из них по 18 значений, от 1 до 18.

Сейчас у меня есть калькулятор, который очень прост - он высчитывает разницу между прошлым и текущим значением и умножает это на 100:

```
var current_rank, new_rank;
$('#rank1').change(function(){
     current_rank = parseInt($(this).val());    
     var result = (new_rank - current_rank) * 100;
     console.log(result);
});
     $('#rank2').change(function(){
     var new_rank = parseInt($(this).val());    
     var result = (new_rank - current_rank) * 100;
     console.log(result);
});
```

Но тут возник вопрос:
Как сделать коэффициенты для этих значений?
Т.е. Чтобы от 1 до 6 цена была 100, от 7 до 12 - 300 и от 13 до 18 - 500?

Для примеров, чтобы было нагляднее:
Человек выбирает из первого поля значение 3, из 2 поля значение 6. Все значения входят в диапазон от 1 до 6, следовательно, (6-3)*100=300.

Значение 1 поля - 5, значение 2 поля - 9
Сейчас происходит так: (9-5)*100=400, но мне нужно, чтобы это рассчитывалось иным путем, поскольку сюда входит значение 6, цена которого 100, а также значения 7,8 и 9, цена которых 300. Следовательно, результат будет такой: 100+(300*3)=1000

Как это сделать, кто знает? А то даже мыслей нет, хотя все просто вроде бы...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простейшим решением будет посчитать всё это в цикле:

```
function diffRank(prev, curr) {
  let res = 0;
  for (let i = curr; i > prev; i--) {
    switch (true) {
      case i >= 13: res += 500; break;
      case i >= 7: res += 300; break;
      default: res += 100;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Однако, можно попробовать решить это аналитически:

```
res += (curr - prev) * 100;
if (curr>6 ) res+= (curr-6) * 200;
if (curr>12 ) res+= (curr-12) * 200;
```

Если воспользоваться тем, как bool выражения приводятся к numeric, можно записать вот такой write-only однострочник:

```js
const diffRate = (p, c) => 100*((c-p)+2*((c>6)*(c-6)+(c>12)*(c-12)));

console.log(diffRate(5, 9));
console.log(diffRate(5, 14))
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже делаю цикл :)

Comment: как вы считаете, правильно ли делать такой подход:
Сделал объект `ranks = {
  1: 100, 
  2: 200, 
  3: 300, 
  4: 400, 
  5: 500,
  6: 600,
  7: 700,
  8: 800,
  9: 900,
 10: 1000,
 11: 1100,
 12: 1200,
 13: 1300,
 14: 1400,
 15: 1500,
 16: 1600,
 17: 1700,
 18: 1800};`
И из него вытаскиваю значения по циклу? Или же не надо так делать?

Comment: Зачем такой объект? Это же просто маппинг `i => 100*i`

Comment: Но если нужно для каждого ранка прописать свою цену и прибавлять ее в конечный результат, то что делать?

Comment: Если так, то да, нормально.